# echo information when parsing and not parsing flags and argument

Tags: linux, bash

```
#function:      usage
#description:   1. parse command line arguments
#               2. for illegal usages, print usage message and exit 1
#               3. otherwise, communicate to main() what flags are set

function usage {  
while getopts ":gn:" OPT; do  
    case $OPT in  
            g) ;;  
            n) name=$OPTARG;;  
            :) echo "$USAGE"  
               exit 1  
            ;;  
            \?) echo "$USAGE"  
                exit 1  
            ;;  
            *) echo "$USAGE"  
               exit 1  
        esac  
done  


shift $(($OPTIND + 1))  
}

#function:      main
#description:   For Part 1:
#               1. use usage() to parse command line arguments
#               2. echo corresponding messages for each flag that is set
#
#               For Part 2:
#               Kill processes based on the case return by `usage`


function main {  

# TODO change the condition so that this line prints when '-g' is set
    usage()  
if [ ! -z "g" ]; then  
    echo graceful kill is present  
fi  

# TODO change the condition so that this line prints when '-n' is set  
if [ ! -z "n" ]; then  
    echo process name is present  
fi  
main $@
```

This is what I write so far, I want to have something like

./KillByName -g 24601
 ​graceful kill is present

or

./KillByName -g
 ​Usage: KillByName [-g] -n  or KillByName [-g]

or

./KillByName -g -n bash
 graceful kill is present
 process name is present

essentially, if there is -g, then it shows it is gracefully killed, and with a name. If there is -n, then it says the name exits and with a name. 
I found my script can print the message of whether graceful kill present or name present, but cannot print the mistake of $USAGE.

BTW: this is only for information of usage, not actually program of killing the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
usage()
```

is not the way you call a function, It should've been

```
usage
```

But there is a problem with that, you're not passing any arguments to the function `usage` from `main`, so it should've been

```
usage "$@" # Double quotes to prevent word splitting
```

Though the term "graceful killing" is a paradox in itself, you could do something like

```
while getopts ":gn:" OPT; do
gracekill=0; //s  
case $OPT in  
        g) gracekill=1;;  
        n) name=$OPTARG;;  
        :) echo "$USAGE"  
           exit 1  
        ;;  
        \?) echo "$USAGE"  
            exit 1  
        ;;  
        *) echo "$USAGE"  
           exit 1  
    esac
    done
    echo "$gracekill $name" # Mind double quotes
```

Then do this :

```
result=$(usage "$@")
if [ ${result:0:1} -eq '1' ]
then
#gracefully kill the application
kill -9  $( pgrep "${result:1}" )
else
#ruthlessly terminate it
kill -15 $( pgrep "${result:1}" )
fi
```

For more on `${var:offset:length}` form, see [[ param expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

<sup>**Notes :** I assume that you're passing the process names to the function, if you're passing the process number, then you don't need the
`pgpep` ie `kill -15 $( pgrep "${result:1}" )` will become `kill -15 "${result:1}"` and so.**Goodluck!**</sup>

Comment: And how to make -g an optional flag. That is, a pid is still needed but, with -g, the process is killed gracefully. But if -g exit but pid does not exist, it will  give false information?

Comment: I'd recommend against running the `usage` function in a subshell (which `result=$(usage "$@")` does) -- it adds the complication of parsing its output (depending on what form the arguments take, this might be tricky to get right), and also the `exit 1`'s in it *don't* actually exit the main script, just the subshell. IMO it's much cleaner to just put the option parsing code inline in the main section of the script, and avoid all this complexity.